# Format the output of JSON object to a more human readable format

Tags: json, powershell

I am getting a JSON object(for property 'Content') for the below powershell code.

```bsh
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method POST | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
```

I want output of 'Content' to be in a more human readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json` pipes at the end. That's it

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method POST | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json
```